# Android Activity Recognition with listener or broadcast receiver?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm wondering, why ActivityRecognitionClient has no method to request updates with standard java listener as parameter? More strange, that in the same time, LocationСlient has [such method](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationClient.html#requestLocationUpdates%28com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest,%20com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener%29) and it works good.

[Official example](http://developer.android.com/training/location/activity-recognition.html) for Activity Recognition looks terrible. A lot of coupled and boilerplate code. It looks like IntentService is sole variant for handling updates from ActivityRecognitionClient. It's extremely uncomfortable.

@Guys from Android Team, why it happens?

As Developer I hope to see requestActivityUpdates(interval, listener) method in next version of Google Play Services.

For now, does anyone know, is it possible to use BroadcastReceiver for handling updates from ActivityRecognitionClient?

Answer (score 5):

> I'm wondering, why ActivityRecognitionClient has no method to request updates with standard java listener as parameter?

Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Beyond that, quoting [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/ActivityRecognitionClient.html#requestActivityUpdates%28long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) for `requestActivityUpdates()`:

> A common use case is that an application wants to monitor activities in the background and perform an action when a specific activity is detected. To do this without needing a service that is always on in the background consuming resources, detected activities are delivered via an intent. The application specifies a PendingIntent callback (typically an IntentService) which will be called when activities are detected.

> It looks like IntentService is sole variant for handling updates from ActivityRecognitionClient.

It's not.

> For now, does anyone know, is it possible to use BroadcastReceiver for handling updates from ActivityRecognitionClient?

There are several types of `PendingIntent`, created from various factory methods. The sample shows using `getService()` to create a `PendingIntent` that will call `startService()`. You are welcome to use any other `PendingIntent`, such as one from `getBroadcast()`, which will call `sendBroadcast()`.

Comment: CommonsWare, thanks for answer! It's great that you mentioned getBroadcast() and sendBroadcast(), it was as missing piece of puzzle for me. Anyway, I still not happy with quality of the training, and inconsistency of requests methods in API. Hope feedback in the question will be heard by guys in Android Team.

Comment: @korovyansk: "Hope feedback in the question will be heard by guys in Android Team" -- the odds of that are roughly on par with the odds of your being struck by lightning. StackOverflow is for Q&A, not for providing feedback. If you get an opportunity to interact with Google engineers, at an event or Hangout or something, that will be a better time to raise your concerns.